# html-code in documentation comment

Tags: php, html, xml, documentation

```
/**
 * tag generation
 * @param string $val value
 * @return string Returns in mode <code><tag>$val</tag></code>
 */
function tag($value) {
...
}
```

Question is how to write '$val' correctly (what have to be instead of '<' and '>') in the doc-comment that .. has displayed correctly in IDE (e.g eclipse).

I've such problem shown in image. How to write, that works in a IDE's bubble?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to echo $val.

Your function should be as follows:

```
echo "<code><tag>".$val."</tag></code>";
```

Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp so you can write your variable to your web page.

Comment: Thank you, &lt;tagname&gt; if i could got the answer.